# Should I initialize my viewController on viewDidLoad or viewWillLayoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I noticed that sometimes on viewDidLoad I got the view size right. Sometimes I don't.

For example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pullToRefreshController = [self.pullToRefreshController initWithDelegate:self];
    PO(self.view);
    PO(self.view.superview);
    PO(self.view.superview.superview);
    PO(self.view.superview.superview.superview);

    while(false);
}
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    PO(self.view);
    PO(self.view.superview);
    PO(self.view.superview.superview);
    PO(self.view.superview.superview.superview);
    while (false);
}
```

at viewDidLoad the size of self.view is still 320 to 480. At viewWillLayoutSubviews that have been fixed.

I wonder what happen in between and where should I initialize stuffs? Or what stuffs should be in viewDidLoad and what stuffs should be in viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is a good place to create and initialize subviews you wish to add to your main view. It is also a good place to further customize your main view. It's also a good place to initialize data structures because any properties should have been set on the view controller by the time this is called. This typically only needs to be done *once*.

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` is where you position and layout the subviews if needed. This will be called after rotations or other events results in the view controller's view being sized. This can happen *many* times in the lifetime of the view controller. You should only layout the views here.

Comment: perfect. It's also a good place to ensure that our view fit the superview (in case of containtment)

Comment: "You should only layout the views here." By 'only', you mean don't create the views here?

Comment: @Honey Do not create views in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.