# Changing the initial game scene in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to change the initial scene being presented to be another class other than the default GameScene class. From reading other questions, I understand I must change this part from the GameViewController:

```
       if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            print(scene)
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

So within the GameScene.swift file I am creating a new class:

```
class MainMenu : SKScene {
   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      print("At least it ran")
      self.scene?.view?.presentScene(GameScene())
   }
}
```

However, when I change the scene to:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu")
```

When I run the project, it gets stuck, but when I run it with the string "GameScene" then it works perfectly. I am doing something wrong loading the MainMenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should separate your scenes into their own files...

Do you have an corresponding SKS file for MenuScene? You need to create one if you are trying to load it with `fileNamed:`

- or -

Use this code to load a SKScene file that is created in code only and not in the Scene editor

```
if let skView = self.view as? SKView {

    if skView.scene == nil {

        let scene = MenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)        
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

and then in your MenuScene file you will need an init func

```
init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

    name = "menuScene"
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why I should present the MenuScene using the viewVillLayoutSubviews() method instead of the viewDidLoad()?

Comment: you can load your scene in wherever is appropriate for your game for you. My Game that I copied that code from I had a need to load it from Layout. There are already a lot of examples explaining the ViewController life cycle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466189/should-i-initialize-my-viewcontroller-on-viewdidload-or-viewwilllayoutsubviews . The point of my example wasn't to focus on where to load the scene but how to load the scene.

Comment: So when I don't create the SKS file, I need to call the initializer to set the size?

Comment: yes...it's 10 lines of code, try it. If it works mark it as correct.