# Broken animation for Slider in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, slider

If I give my slider initial value (e.g. slider.value = 5) and then I am moving it, the animations are broken and the “thumb” seems to be jumping between current position and position for value 5 (but again, only when I am “sliding” it). When I don’t give it an initial position, no problem. Have you run into the same/similar problem?

My code is here:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Playercontroller: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - User Interface Properties

    var artworkView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rivuletInSpring"))
    let infoLabel = UILabel()
    let timeLabel = UILabel()
    let startButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let stopButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let slider = UISlider()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var timer = Timer()
    var time: Int = 5
    var navigationTitle = "Rivulet in the Spring"
    var soundName = "rivuletInSpringMelody"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .black
        navigationItem.title = "\(navigationTitle)" // set to a value based on a pressed button

        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(soundName)", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        }
        catch
        {
            // finish! probably use a notification
        }

    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        infoLabel.text = "Duration in mins: "
        infoLabel.textColor = .white
        infoLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 25.0)

        timeLabel.text = String(Int(slider.value))
        timeLabel.textColor = .white
        timeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 25.0)

        slider.maximumValue = 60
        slider.minimumValue = 1
        //slider.value = 5
        slider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(sliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

        startButton.backgroundColor = .black
        startButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        startButton.tintColor = .orange
        startButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 30.0)
        startButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        startButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play), for: .touchUpInside)

        stopButton.backgroundColor = .black
        stopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopButton.tintColor = .orange
        stopButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 30.0)
        stopButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        stopButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        stopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stop), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(artworkView)
        artworkView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(timeLabel)
        timeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(slider)
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(startButton)
        startButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(stopButton)
        stopButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            artworkView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 414),
            artworkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: artworkView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 170.0/414.0),
            artworkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            artworkView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            artworkView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: artworkView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            infoLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -11.0),
            timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: artworkView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 7.0),
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            startButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            startButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.bottomAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            startButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            startButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            stopButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.bottomAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            stopButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 20),
            stopButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            stopButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            ])

    }

    func sliderValueChanged(){
        timeLabel.text = String(Int(slider.value))
    }

}
```

Comment: include the *relevant* code onsite, not on some external site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the *initial value* of the `slider` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  That function runs thousands of times including while you are dragging the slider thumb.  If you want to give your slider an initial value, inside of the override for `viewDidLoad` would be a better choice.

In fact, all of the code you have in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` should be moved to `viewDidLoad` or into a `setup` function that is called by `viewDidLoad`.  You don't want to be adding subviews in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Alright, I tried that one as well and it didn't work back then and it didn't work this time either. However, for first time I as well set the min and max in viewDidLoad and it worked! Thanks! And if I can ask, why is it better to add subviews to viewDidLoad? Because viewWillLayoutSubviews runs thousands of times?

Comment: As I can't edit my previous comment any longer, I just want to say that I have found an answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466189/should-i-initialize-my-viewcontroller-on-viewdidload-or-viewwilllayoutsubviews)